# A voltage graph in PGF plots

Tags: pgfplots

Would it be possible to achieve this in PGF plots? I can manage to get a sine wave and draw the sawtooth looking wave but cant get it all together
[image]

Comment: For two plots on the same axis, use \addplot.  groupplots will place two sets of axes above each other.  Reducing the spacing to nothing might be difficult.  And to add labels, define a \coordinate using cs units inside the axes environment, then use the named coordinate afterward for the label (\node).

Comment: @JohnKormylo If there are no marks on the _y_-axis, it would be easier to simply do the two plots on one axis with an offset and the tick labels removed.

Comment: thanks for the help, ill eventually get there, learning along the way ..

Comment: Actually, you could probably add the node inside the axis environment.  The reason for doing it later is to put the label on top of shaded areas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another way to implement Jesse's plot without using loops is to use `abs(sin(x))` for the rectified sine wave, `exp(-(0.0015*mod(x+90,180))` for the repeating exponential function, and `max(<function a>, <function b>)` for combining the two:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:1.5*360,
    samples=4*360,
    xtick=\empty,
    width=10cm, height=4cm,
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits=false
]
\addplot [densely dashed] {abs(sin(x))};
\addplot [very thick] {max(abs(sin(x)), exp(-(0.0015*mod(x+90,180)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats great, thanks alot, how could you do the sawtooth using your method?

Comment: That is what TikZ was meant to be. Genius solution Ben Quinton.

Comment: @jake, could you help me generate a waveform in little different than above as intended here at  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/688285/18678

Answer (score 6):

This is one possible solution via  PGFplots. The rectified curve is an exponentially decay function with a large time constant, not a sloped line.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\def\arch{1.7*pi/3}   %
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$},xmin=-3,xmax=21,
             ylabel={$i_D$},ymin=0,ymax=5,
             axis x line=center, 
             axis y line=left, enlargelimits=upper]
% draw sine functions
\addplot [dashed,thin,domain=-pi:6*pi,smooth]{-2*sin(deg(0.5*x))};
\addplot [dashed,thin,domain=-pi:6*pi,smooth]{ 2*sin(deg(0.5*x))};

% draw the rectified curves automatically via foreach skill
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {-1/0/1,1/2/3,3/4/5,5/6/7}{
\addplot [thick,domain=\i*pi:{\j*pi+\arch}, ] {2*e^(-0.05*(x-\i*pi)};  % exponentially decay curves, not a line
\addplot [thick,domain={\j*pi+\arch}:\k*pi, smooth]{ 2*sin(deg(0.5*x))};
\addplot [thick,domain={\j*pi+\arch}:\k*pi, smooth]{-2*sin(deg(0.5*x))};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Half-Wave Rectifier Waveform}
\label{halfcycle}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```