# Waveform at the output of a filter connected after a Half Wave Rectifier Circuit

Tags: tikz-pgf, waveform, half-wave

I am trying to generate a waveform of a half-wave rectifier circuit. All I could do by modifying the [code given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204493/18678) is the following:

1. First modification code:

   ```
    \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=0:1.5*360,
        samples=4*360,
        xtick=\empty,
        width=10cm, height=4cm,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis line style={-},
        ymax=1.5,
        ymin=0,
        enlarge x limits=false,
    ]
    \addplot [densely dashed] {sin(x)};
    \addplot [thick] {max(sin(x), exp(-(0.0015*mod(x+90, 720)))};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
   ```

and the output I get from the above-modified code is
[image: first modification]

2. Now, the further modification on the above code, specifically at

   ```
    \addplot [thick] {max(sin(x), exp(-(0.0015*mod(x+270, 720)))};
   ```

gives me the output
[image: second modification]

**However**, I would like an output waveform this way. Is there a way to achieve a waveform like this using either pgfplots or simply tikz package?
[image: intended output waveform]

**Note:** Charging part in the first half cycle should start from 0/initial value.

Comment: You have the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204461/a-voltage-graph-in-pgf-plots?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hi! What is the slope of the line segments?  I imagine rhat these segments live on parallel lines.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro, that's the output of the full wave rectifier circuit with a filter. I am, in fact, looking for the output waveform of a filter connected after a half-wave rectifier circuit. These two outputs are different from each other: one output has a ripple on closely repeated half waves while the other one has ripples at 2pi away half waves

Comment: @DanielN I have no idea how it is to be found out; however, yes, slopes look parallel to each other. It's an output waveform of a filter connected right after any half-wave rectifier circuit. I am trying to modify the idea provided by Jake in his answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204493/18678

Comment: @DanielN, these should be exponentially falling lines from the lowpass after the diode. If the were parallel, they would also be almost horizontal. // BTW, it then makes no sense that the voltage follows the sine wave, if large enough, but drops exp. after that …

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about (@MS-SPO and Khaaba).  But form a certain distance, it seems to me that there are at least two ways of drawing the curves.  First, one has explicit solutions are draw the corresponding graphs.  Second, we are mainly concerned with the desired image and try to produce something that approaches it.  I vote for the second solution in this case, unless you can provide a mathematical formula.

Comment: @DanielN, we call it electronics. See e.g. here https://www.elektroniktutor.de/analogtechnik/an_pict/glr_m1c.png and here https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B74ZTAS3s6o/maxresdefault.jpg . In layz terms, the current became kind of slow ... allways ...

Comment: @DanielN, I appreciate the two ways you have put forward. I borrowed the code and its mathematical expression provided by Jake in one of his replies[link provided above in my description]. All I needed is to generate and waveform something like this https://electric-shocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Filtered-Output-of-Half-wave-Rectifier.jpg

Comment: @Khaaba, even that one is wrong, viewed from physics or electronics. At best it‘s an oversimplification under certain conditions, determined by frequency and time constants, mainly.

Comment: Technically you are charging and discharging a capacitor, although the charging part is nearly instantaineous (depending on the transformer used).

Comment: @{John Kormylo, MS-SPO}, yes, I agree that the waveform of the first half cycle is, in fact, wrong; however, I tried my best to reproduce the drawing available here [jake's answer]. Charging part is missing in the first half cycle.

Comment: So, who will open the chat room for those still interested to discuss? Honestly, I think the tikz-part is clear now, and the electronics background, too. CU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The drawing depends on two parameters, `\mainTW` and `\secondT`.  The first si slightly bigger then `pi/2` and the latter smaller than `pi/4`.  They control the "wave".

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\begin{document}

\tikzmath{%
  real \mainTW, \secondT, \angleW, \piW, \boundW;
  \piW = 3.14159;
  \mainTW = \piW/2 +.1;
  \secondT = .22*\piW;
  \angleW = {atan(cos(\mainTW r))};
  \boundW = 5.3*\piW;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={scale=.8}, xscale=.7]
  \draw[->, thin] (-.5, 0) -- (\boundW, 0) node[below=1ex] {$t$};
  \draw[->, thin] (0, -.5) -- (0, 1.5);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-.5, 0) rectangle (\boundW, 1.5);
    \draw[dashed, very thin,
    variable=\t, domain=-.5:\boundW, samples=80] plot (\t, {sin(\t r)});

  \draw[blue, thick, variable=\t]
  [domain=0:\secondT, samples=30] plot (\t, {sin(\t r)})
  \foreach \j in {0, 1, 2}{%
    [domain={2*\j*\piW +\secondT}:{2*\j*\piW +\mainTW}, samples=30]
    plot (\t, {sin(\t r)})
    to[out=\angleW, in=179]
    ($({2*(\j+1)*\piW +\secondT}, {sin(\secondT r)})$)
  };  
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Again, a nice drawing, which is factually wrong. Check electronics, please. May be it's time to stop replicating this kind of misinformation.

Comment: @MS-SPO supply a formula and the drawing might be easily modified or corrected.

Comment: What needed to be specified: a) the circuitry, b) its parameters (R, L, C, ...), at least. It's a comparable situation to posting code snippets here without giving the preamble ;-) // An analytical solution is difficult. Easier is running a circuit simulation and taking its graphical output or redrawing it. Best is measuring the circuit with a scope, wee my early comments on the question. // So, there's some duty left for the TO.

Comment: @MS-SPO, I had been just trying to visualize the waveform using tikz, and of course, without simulating the actual circuit. If you have a better drawing using tikz, please provide the same. I would instead simulate the same in MATLAB or SPICE; but I have been drawing circuits and doing its output visualization only in tikz. Maybe someday, when I become expert in tikz, I may come up with a proper drawing using proper component values

Comment: @MS-SPO when you study an electronic circuit, there are several approximation level that you can engage with. This is one. It's not *the real output*, but that *does not exist* really. Normally when you design a peak detector you consider the discharge linear and starting on the sinusoidal peak --- going in more details means a) you have another problem b) you are studying the behavior of the circuit for a very edge application.

Answer (score 3):

I think you got the phase wrong (in the linked answer it didn't matter due to the `abs(sin(...`. I tried to plot the ramp (the "recurring" time on x) separately to understand what happens, and I have this --- notice the usage of an auxiliary function to simplify the equations:

```latex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
     declare function={
        ramp(\x)=mod(\x+270, 360)/360;
     }
     ]
 \begin{axis}[
     domain=0:1.5*360,
     samples=4*360,
     % xtick=\empty,
     width=10cm, height=4cm,
     axis x line=bottom,
     axis y line=left,
     axis line style={-},
     ymax=1.5,
     ymin=0,
     enlarge x limits=false,
 ]
 \addplot [densely dashed] {sin(x)};
 \addplot [thick] {max(sin(x), exp(-ramp(x))};
 \addplot [thick, blue, dashed] {exp(-ramp(x))};
 \addplot [red] {ramp(x)};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I'm using +270 instead of -90 because the module operation for negative x is symmetric, and we don't want this here.

Removing the auxiliary info I added to understand what was happening, you have:

[image]

Notice that to have the correct "detach" (tangent) you have to put in real numbers form the detector...

Comment: Again, a nice drawing, which is factually wrong. Check electronics, please. May be it's time to stop replicating this kind of misinformation.

Comment: @MS-SPO, Rmano was creating the exact waveform I was looking for. I thank him for his wonderful code. I agree that the initial charging part in the first half cycle is wrong. That is wrong on my part for missing that idea while I was desperately trying to recreate the waveform from Jake's reply.

Comment: @MS-SPO I have been teaching electronics since 1994, publishing research on instrumentation since then. This is (modulo adjusting the value for the correct "detach" event) a quite nice didactic approximation for the steady state 1-wave peak detector. I'd like to know what "check electronics" means. I hope you are not advocating for the "first-period waveform," which does not exist because the sinusoidal phase is normally a random value when the circuit is engaged. Yes, the real waveforms will be (slightly) different. Yes, this is the approximation when you *design* a peak detector.

Comment: @Khaaba thanks --- this waveform is a *steady state first order* approximation, and so the first part is not the "first charging" whatever that means. You connect the peak detector at t=-∞ for ant practical purpose, or you have a worse problem. 

Comment: @Rmano, thanks for your comments. Well, 1994 perhaps you could have been one of the analog IC design engineers I was training in various topics. // So, muscles shown, case closed, at least for me ;-)

Comment: @MS-SPO No offense taken, nor intended at all. Points of view may differ, even in science.